# Duda menú desplegable

Tags: html, css, menú

Esta es mi barra de menú:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero hacer que al poner el ratón encima de "Trabajos", me salgan dos submenús, tipo Dropdown, como Trabajo1 y Trabajo2. He probado varias cosas pero me cargo todo. Os dejo aquí el código:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-top: 55px;
}

header {
  background: #4357ad;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.menu {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu .logo {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.menu .logo img {
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 22px;
}

.menu .btn-menu {
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.menu .logo:hover {
  background: #4357ad;
  /* color fondo logo*/
}

menu .enlaces {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}

.menu .enlaces a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.menu .enlaces i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.menu .enlaces a:hover {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  color: #4357ad;
}

main {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

main article h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

main article hr {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  height: 2px;
  background: #4357ad;
  border: none;
}

main article p {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}


/* efectos del menu*/

.headroom {
  will-change: transform;
  transition: transform 200ms linear;
}

.headroom--pinned {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}

.headroom--unpinned {
  transform: translateY(-30%);
}


/* mediaquries */

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  header .menu {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  header .menu .logo {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
  }
  header .menu .logo .btn-menu {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  header .menu .enlaces {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <nav class="menu">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/neymar.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a href="#" class="btn-menu" id="btn-menu"><i class="icono fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>

    <div class="enlaces" id="enlaces">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> Inicio</a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Blog</a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i> Trabajos</a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Contacto</a>
    </div>
  </nav>

</header>
```

Comment: "_He probado varias cosas pero me cargo todo_". ¿Podrías compartir los intentos y cómo fallaron? De ese modo se consiguen dos cosas: 1) podríamos revisar el código para ver si contiene algún error; y 2) si ya intentaste algo y no funciona, nos ahorraría tiempo porque no tendríamos que comprobar esa opción.

Answer (score 1):

Me voy a enfocar más en la estructura de tu menú que en los estilos, por lo que te voy a mostrar la estructura de un menú típico, ya que no se realizan directamente con enlaces tal y como muestras en tu ejemplo.

Para los menús se suelen utilizar las listas `ul` (unordered list) junto con `li` (list item). La estructura de un menú, por tanto, sería de la siguiente manera:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li id="etiquetaConSubmenu">
     <ul id="submenu">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

La primera etiqueta `ul` sería la que englobaría el menú, siendo los `li` cada uno de los enlaces de tu menú. Dentro de estos enlaces, podrías introducir otro `ul` (es decir, una lista dentro de un item) con sus respectivos `li` para generar el submenú.

Por último, simplemente oculta por defecto el submenu y muéstralo cuando hagas `hover` por encima de la etiqueta que contiene el submenú.

Ejemplo:

```css
#enlaces .enlace{
  display: inline-block;
}

#trabajo li{
  display: none;
}

#trabajo:hover li{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <nav class="menu">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/neymar.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a href="#" class="btn-menu" id="btn-menu"><i class="icono fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>

    <ul id="enlaces">
      <li class="enlace"><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
      <li class="enlace"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li id="trabajo" class="enlace">
        <a href="#">Trabajos</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

No se si te podrás guiar con esto que tengo yo de una barra de navegación con la que me ayudaron hace tiempo @Luis Daniel Rovira Contreras.
Podrías encontrarlo mejor explicado [en la página de w3chools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp) tiene varios [ejemplos que quizá](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_filter)  mejor que lo mio.
Suerte.

```js
// Offset for Site Navigation
/*$('#siteNav').affix({
 offset: {
  top: 100
 }
})*/
/*script para despliegue automatico*/
    $( ".dropdown-toggle" ).hover(
  function() {
// hover in
$( this ).next('.dropdown-menu').show("slow");
  }, function() {
// hover out
var menuHover = !$(this).next(".dropdown-menu").is(":hover");
if (menuHover) {
  $( this ).next('.dropdown-menu').hide("slow");     
}
  }
);

$(".dropdown-menu").mouseleave(function () {
  if (!$(this).prev().is(":hover")) {
$(this).hide("slow");
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
}

a {
    color: yellowgreen;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: forestgreen;
}

p {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-image: url('http://i64.tinypic.com/11j9dad.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    
    <script>
        $( ".dropdown-toggle" ).hover(
  function() {
    // hover in
    $( this ).next('.dropdown-menu').show("slow");
  }, function() {
    // hover out
    var menuHover = !$(this).next(".dropdown-menu").is(":hover");
    if (menuHover) {
      $( this ).next('.dropdown-menu').hide("slow");     
    }
  }
);

$(".dropdown-menu").mouseleave(function () {
  if (!$(this).prev().is(":hover")) {
$(this).hide("slow");
  }
});
    </script>
</head>
<nav id="siteNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Logo and responsive toggle -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> 
                 LOGO
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- Navbar links -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="Principal.html">CASA</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">RECURSOS</a>
                    </li>
     <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">SOBRE MI <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="about-us">
       <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.es/maps/place/Calle+del+Olivar,+5,+05400+La+Parra,+%C3%81vila/@40.224582,-5.0602472,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0xd40756225aeabbd:0xcc0228cc3c4de2c8!8m2!3d40.2245779!4d-5.0580585?hl=es">UBICACION</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">PROYECTOS</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">CURRICULUM</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="Contacto.html">CONTACTO</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
    </body>
    </html>
```